# Get all child in hierarchy by LINQ

Tags: linq, hierarchy

i have 3 table

- Category (main), have rootId
- ChildCategory, have rootId too
- Category_ChildCategory (n-n) between Category and ChildCategory
  So i have data

```
Category
-----------------
ID  ParrentId
1   NULL
2   1
3   2
4   NULL
5   NULL
6   NULL
```

```
ChildCategory
---------------------
ChildId ChildParentId
1   NULL
2   NULL
3   2
4   NULL
5   NULL
```

```
Category_ChildCategory
---------------------------
CategoryId  ChildCategoryId
1       1
1       2
2       3
```

So if we select "Category" with Id = 1
The result will be

```
Category: 1,2,3
ChildCategory: 1,2,3
```

Because Category 1 have child (rootId = 1) is category_2 - same level with it and category_2 have child is childCategory)3
And category_1 have 2 child category is childCategory_1 and childCategory_2

---

If we select childCategory 2, so result will be
Category: NaN
ChildCategory: 2,3

Comment: What did you try? What were the results?

Comment: @EddyLee What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Thank for all people who care about my question !
I have solved it by use SQL CTE query, with 2 CTE one for Category and one for CategoryChild

Here is my code

Category CTE

```
;WITH categoryCTE AS 
 (
  SELECT a.CATEGORY_ID, a.CATEGORY_ROOT_ID
  FROM CATEGORY a
  WHERE CATEGORY_ID = @CATEGORY_ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT  a.CATEGORY_ID, a.CATEGORY_ROOT_ID
  FROM CATEGORY a JOIN categoryCTE c ON a.CATEGORY_ROOT_ID = c.CATEGORY_ID
  ),
  childCategoryCTE AS (
 
  SELECT a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ID, a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ROOT_ID
  FROM CHILD_CATEGORY a
  WHERE CHILD_CATEGORY_ID IN (select CHILD_CATEGORY_ID from CATEGORY_CHILD_CATEGORY
WHERE CATEGORY_ID = @CATEGORY_ID)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ID, a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ROOT_ID
  FROM CHILD_CATEGORY a JOIN childCategoryCTE c ON a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ROOT_ID = c.CHILD_CATEGORY_ID
  )
```

ChildCategory CTE

```
;WITH childCategoryCTE AS (
 
  SELECT a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ID, a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ROOT_ID
  FROM CHILD_CATEGORY a
  WHERE CHILD_CATEGORY_ID = @CHILD_CATEGORY_ID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ID, a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ROOT_ID
  FROM CHILD_CATEGORY a JOIN childCategoryCTE c ON a.CHILD_CATEGORY_ROOT_ID = c.CHILD_CATEGORY_ID
  )
```